# 100% CPU usage reported, but no processes using the CPU

Tags: linux, debian, cpu-usage, top, htop

I am running Debian 10 (kernel 4.19.0-18-amd64) on bare metal and I have recently noticed strange CPU usage.

[Screenshot of htop, sorted by CPU%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5seIq.png)

[Screenshot of top, sorted by CPU%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvkZW.png)

As you can see, 100% CPU usage is reported over all of the cores but the reported usage for each individual process does not seem to back this up.

I have looked at iotop

[iotop, sorted in ascending order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mYPk.png)

Where else can I look to try and hunt down this resource hog?

Thanks.

Comment: Exactly the same problem! At least you are not alone bro!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that according to top, 98.5% CPU is used by "niced" processes (note `98.5 ni`). Niced processes are those having positive "nice" value, i.e. lower priority. As the next step, open "top" again, sort by "NI" value, and look for the higher values (from 1 to 19).

Answer (score 0):

In general, even on 100% CPU activities without 100%RAM activities simultaneously , We consider it is just ok until it can get done when tasks list finishes.

It is more important con consider LoadAvg vs RAM vs CPU in a big set of data.
until all of them are about 100% and LoadAvg around 5 per physical core + 2 per virtualcpu (hyperthreading) , just survey , over start investigating & managing processes priorities & Affect any new tasks to dedicated (v)cpu with `taskset` until all goes back to lower consumption of resources.